# Bieberbach's Theorem

Tags: gr.group-theory

Can someone explain me, what is the meaning of the term "Compact Fundamental Domain" in the following theorem?

"Every discrete group of isometries acting on the n-dimensional euelidean space R^n with compact fundamental domain contains n linearly independent translations" ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain

Comment: The correct form is "splain."  See http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0043208/quotes 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fundamental domain X is a subset such that:

1)  If U is the interior, each G-orbit intersects U at most once.

2)  If C is the closure, then each G-orbit intersects C at least once.